# How to add dots to every 3 digits in react-native TextInput while user types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a price input like this:

```
<Input
   keyboardType={"decimal-pad"}
   inputStyle={{color: "#EDF5E1"}}
   value={this.state.price.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")}
   onChangeText={(newPrice)=>this.setState({price: newPrice.toString().replace(".", ""})}
/>
```

My aim is to add dots to every 3 digits while the user is typing! like this(12.443.355)
this piece of code `price.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")}` works fine, but as user modifies the number, it messes up!

> note that my problem differs from [JavaScript; How to set dot after three digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992340/javascript-how-to-set-dot-after-three-digits), I'm able to add dots, but it messes up when the user modifies it.

Comment: I found a NPM library which could help to you to solve it. Please check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format

Comment: Is this, by any chance, supposed to be for entering an IP address?  Because there may be a better way.  There are likely IP address components available.

Comment: This may just be typos, so only commenting for now. First, your value set needs to use `this.state.price`, not just `price`. Second, your `onChangeText` handler is inconsistent. Change the arrow-function parameter name from `price` to avoid collision with the state name, and remove the superfluous `.toString()`

Comment: `price: to.toString()` looks like a typo.  did you mean `price: price.toString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what **"to"** in `to.toString().replace(".", "")` is but I'm sure you should use `to.toString().replace(/\./g, "")` instead of **replace(".", "")** because **replace** only replaces the first occurance in the string by default.

Comment: I'm sorry, "to" is a typo, it's "price", but your solution doesn't work I get this error: "price.toString(...).replaceAll is not a function". looks like 'replaceAll' function doesn't exist at all!

Comment: @BlueTurtle I'm so sorry, my bad... I will edit my answer.